# How to print karate api configuration settings

Tags: karate

I am trying to print karate configuration settings(like readTimeout, connectTimeout etc.) in a test. Below is the sample request and I am configuring readTimeout and would like to print the same. Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance

```
Given url 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com'
And path 'api/v1/employees'
* configure readTimeout = 100000
* print readTimeout //nothing printed
When method GET
Then status 200
And print response
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported as most teams don't need this. It sounds like you are attempting to write some custom framework using Karate. You are welcome to contribute code as this is an open-source project - or switch to some other framework.